# Function Not Deploying to Azure Function from VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a Python Azure Function, and after creating the function locally (which I confirmed works in the debugger), I can't find a way to deploy it to my Azure Function App. I choose to "Deploy to Function app..." which appears to complete successfully, but the function never shows on Azure Portal. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: What are the modules you are importing?

Answer (score 1):

I have created the below timer trigger function.

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="*/5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

**requirement.txt**

```py
azure-functions
```

**Please note**, If you are importing any other modules in your  `function_app.py` file, you need to add the correct version of that module in `requirement.txt` file.

Even I am deploying using below option-

[image]

Post successful deployment, I am able to see the function in my function app.

[image]

You can also use `func azure functionapp publish <func-app-name>` command to deploy the function to the Function App.

Please make sure to add all the modules in the `requirement.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up creating it with Model V2 and it worked - not sure why V1 was giving me an issue.

Comment: @MarkR were you importing any other modules apart from logging and azure.functions?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Thanks, this worked for me. I was importing pandas and azure-storage-blob and needed to add them to the requirements.txt file. Can you explain why I did not need to add logging or os module to the requirement.txt file? I was also importing those 2